# Linq select objects by comparing from two lists of type int

Tags: c#, linq, int, compare

I have a `List<Organisation>` Organisations.

Each `Organisation` has a property `List<int> Categories`.

I also have a separate `List<int> DisplayCategories`

I want to create a new `List<Organisation>` called `DisplayOrganisations`.

`DisplayOrganisations` will contain `Organisation`'s whos `Categories` appear in my `List<int> DisplayCategories`.

How can I achieve this using linq or lambda?

The following is incorrect:

```
DisplayOrganisations = (from o in Organisations
                        where o.Categories.Intersect(DisplayCategories.CategoryIds) 
                        select o).ToList();
```

I get an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'bool'

I believe that this is because I am selecting Organisations who's sub list of Categories need to be compared to a separate list DisplayCategories.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please dont use second approach in my answer. Use first one. As its proven Intersect is better for larger collections. See the answer again.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary thank you, I have amended my code to use intersect just like your update,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure intersect will not give a boolean. you may want to check if there is any elements exist in it use `Any`.

```
DisplayOrganisations = Organisations
                       .Where(o => o.Categories.Intersect(DisplayCategories.CategoryIds)
                                               .Any()).ToList();
```

<s>Or better approach.
    DisplayOrganisations = Organisations.Where(o => o.Categories
                           .Any(xDisplayCategories.CategoryIds.Contains)).ToList();</s>

As you can see in the image Intersect uses hashset which is faster than second approach because Hashset has time complexity of `O(1)` for both adding and removing items. So in general Intersect is `O(n+m)`. but the second approach using `Any` and `Contains` had time complexity of `O(n^2)` which could become much slower.Thanks to [Dmitry Dovgopoly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1237491/dmitry-dovgopoly).

[image]

Comment: i guess intersect takes much more time than doing linear search. im not sure what is time complexity though but i appreciate if you share your knowledge so i will fix my answer and also learn something ;) @DmitryDovgopoly

Comment: Actually the second approach as much worse. Intersect uses `hashset` and is fast. `Any` applies the method to all the elements and complexity is n*n. You could optimize it by creating a hashset from `xDisplayCategories.CategoryIds`

Comment: Thanks for the information! much appreciated. I didnt know intersect uses hashset. So i think this is probably the fastest way to find out that two lists contains at least one same item. (ignoring micro optimization)  @DmitryDovgopoly

Comment: It depends on `Data` and usage. `Intersect` will create new `HashSet` for each `Organization` here. It can be really good idea to create a `HashSet ` from `xDisplayCategories.CategoryIds` and then use `Any` if there are many `organizations` and they have huge `Categories` lists.

Comment: Ive Gone through intersect implementation. as you can see in this image it will create a Set from second argument . so no worries!  @DmitryDovgopoly

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly thank you for pointing out that the solution that uses Intersect is superior.

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly I got what you mean. Since display category is constant during query you can create one hashset from it. Good point!

Answer (score 2):

If you need only those Organisations where all elements are in `CategoryIds` list you can use mixture of `Except()` and `Any()` methods :

```
var DisplayOrganisations  = Organisations.Where(o => 
                         !o.Categories.Except(DisplayCategories.CategoryIds).Any()).ToList();
```

If you just want to check that there is at least one id in the list of ids you can use `.Any` method :

```
var DisplayOrganisations  = Organisations.Where(o => o.Categories
                                      .Any(DisplayCategories.CategoryIds.Contains)).ToList();
```